# Angular 2. Guard that depends on response from server

Tags: angular

I have a singleton service:

```
export class CarService {
  public currentCar: BehaviorSubject<Car> = new BehaviorSubject(null); 
  constructor(private jsonApiService: JsonApiService) {

      this.jsonApiService.get(`.../activeCar`);
        .subscribe(data => {
          if(data) {
              this.setActiveCar(data);
          }
        })
    }
  }

  public setActiveCar(activeCar: Car): void {
    this.currentBrokerageAccount.next(activeCar);
  }
}
```

Then, I use `currentCar` in the guard:

```
canActivateChild(childRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    if (!this.canActivate()) {
      return false;
    }
    if (!this.carService.currentCar.getValue() && state.url !== '/settings') {
      this.router.navigate(['/settings']);
    }

    return true;
}
```

The guard checks current car and if there is data then allow to open page, otherwise redirects to settings page where user have to select car. So, the problem is when I use menu in the application then all works fine, but when I open page in first time(or F5) then I am always  redirected to settings page. I understand the reason: it's because `carService`  has not got the active car from a server yet and `currentCar` is null. How to solve it properly?

PS. The flow is following: After authentication user see all features in the applicatione if car is selected. But, if car is not selected, only one url is available and it's the `settings`. So, if car is not selected I redirect user to the settings page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BehaviourSubject you're requesting value is probably still evaluating the selected car from the server. You could use an AsyncSubject that fetch the value and then complete, and instead of "requesting" the current value from the service, you should subscribe to the subject and let him push the value to you.

```
//in your service
currentCar$ : AsyncSubject<Car> = new AsyncSubject();
this.jsonApiService.get(`.../activeCar`).subscribe(
    (car) => {
         currentCar$.next(car);
         currentCar$.complete(car);
    }
);

//in your guard
//instead of getValue() subscribe to the AsyncSubject
//you should probably handle the "null" case too
this.carService.currentCar$.subscribe(
     (car) => {
         if ( !car && state.url !== '/settings' ){
             this.router.navigate(['/settings']);
         }
     }
);
```

The subscription will recieve the value emitted from AsyncSubject just before it's completion.

Comment: The AsyncSubject is what I need. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
export class CarService {

  private data: any;

  constructor(private jsonApiService: JsonApiService) {
    }
    getCar(): Observable<any> {
      return this.jsonApiService.get('url')
        .map((response: Response) => {
          this.data = response.json().data;
            return this.data;
          }
        );
    }

    hasCarData() {
      return data ? true : false;
    }
  }

  public setActiveCar(activeCar: Car): void {
    this.currentBrokerageAccount.next(activeCar);
  }
}

canActivateChild(childRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    if (!this.canActivate()) {
      return false;
    }

    if(state.url !== '/settings') {
      this.carService.getCar()
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        if (!this.carService.hasCarData()) {
          this.router.navigate(['/settings']);  
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      });
    } else {
      return true;
    }
}
```